# What happened to my settings?

Tags: uninstall, libreoffice, system-settings, gnome-control-center

I removed LibreOffice because I use Kingsoft Office for everything (since I come from Microsoft Office, I find it simpler to use). But now, **this** happened to my settings:

[image]

Most of the options are gone, there are just five left. What should I do? Reinstalling LibreOffice didn't do anything. Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I'm not quite professional and I don't know much about Ubuntu, since I'm now using it two days. Please keep it simple for a noob like me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the *ubuntu-desktop* package.

Then don't remove it unless you really know what you are doing. ;)